# Setting Login with User Name and Password default option for Jetpack Admin Login

Tags: admin, login, plugin-jetpack

I am working on a new project with Wordpress using the Jetpack plugin. Jetpack add the option to Login using Wordpress Account as the default method of login, if not, then you have to click on a link under to login as traditionally was done with user name and password.

Is there a way to flip this.. User name and password be the default and login with Wordpress.com account be the optional second screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the `functions.php` in your active theme folder. For me it is `/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php`.

Add this line to the end of the file:

```
add_filter( 'jetpack_sso_default_to_sso_login', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: That does it. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: you can find sso settings here: https://jetpack.com/support/sso/